# Best practice regarding firing and handling of .NET events

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, asynchronous, deadlock

It is obvious that firing events inside of a lock (i.e. critical section) is prone to deadlocks due to the possibility that the event handler may block on some asynchronous operation that also needs to acquire the same lock. Now, design-wise there are two possible solutions that come to my mind:

1. If it is needed to fire an event inside a lock, then always fire the event asynchronously. This can be performed by using ThreadPool, for example, if the firing order of the events does not matter. If the order of the events must be preserved, then a single event firing thread can be used to fire the events in order, but asynchronously.
2. The class/library that fires the events does not need to take any necessary precautions to prevent the deadlock and just fire the event inside the lock. In this case it is the event handler's responsibility to process the event asynchronously if it performs locking (or any other blocking operation) inside the event handler. If the event handler does not conform to this rule, then it should suffer the consequences in case a deadlock occurs.

I honestly think that the second option is better in terms of separation of concerns principle as the event-firing code should not guess what the event handler may or may not do.

However, practically, I am inclined to take the first route since the second option seems to converge to the point that every event handler must now run all event-handling code asynchronously, since most of the time it is not clear whether some series of calls performs a blocking operation or not. For complex event-handlers, tracing all possible paths (and, moreover, keeping track of it as the code evolves) is definitely not an easy task. Therefore, solving the problem in one place (where the event is fired) seems to be preferable.

I am interested in seeing if there are other alternative solutions that I may have overlooked and what possible advantages/disadvantages and pitfalls can be attributed to each possible solution.

Is there a best practice for this kind of situation?

Answer (score 2):

There is a third option: Delay raising the event until the lock is released. Normally, locks are taken for a short time. It is usually possible to delay raising the event till after lock (but on the same thread).

The BCL almost never calls user code under a lock. This is an explicit design principle of theirs. For example `ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate` does *not* call the factory while under a lock. This counter-intuitive behavior causes many Stack Overflow questions because it can lead to multiple factory invocations for the same key.

Comment: I definitely agree, that is another possible solution. Although it is very easy to simply see whether the method that fires the event has a lock in it, it is usually very difficult or impossible to know if one of the calling methods (in the call-chain leading to the event-firing method) already has a lock in place. In such cases it is very difficult to fire the event outside of lock context. BCL is a relevant example, but I'm not sure if it's applicable to application code with complex business logic, since BCL is just a collection of independent (usually small and non-thread-safe) classes.

Comment: @exc you are right: If you code makes heavy use of locking and deep callstacks in a locked region this is a big problem. I'd like to suggest that maybe you should reevaluate whether such sophisticated threading code is really the best solution?! Especially considering that deadlocks are most fatal errors in that the app never recovers without manual intervention.; In your case it is probably safe and easy to push the callback invocation to the thread-pool. This is my new answer.

Comment: I sincerely thank you for submitting an answer, and would like to point that I agree with you in principle, and I try really hard not to write such un-manageable code. However, please bear in mind that such an idealistic approach usually has little applicability where you have a large codebase (millions of lines of code), and most of it is legacy code that had been written by tens of people and is currently being maintained by a group of at least 15 people. I am trying to incrementally improve the code as far as I can, and hence my question.

Comment: @exc sure, I completely get that. The delay approach is probably not applicable. Neither is rewriting the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

> I honestly think that the second option is better in terms of separation of concerns principle as the event-firing code should not guess what the event handler may or may not do.

I don't think the first option violates separation of concerns. Extract an `AsyncEventNotifier` class and have your event-generating object delegate to it, something like (obviously not complete):

```
class AsyncEventNotifier
{
    private List<EventListener> _listeners;

    public void AddEventListener(EventListener listener) { _listeners.add(listener); }
    public void NotifyListeners(EventArgs args)
    {
        // spawn a new thread to call the listener methods
    }
    ....
}

class EventGeneratingClass
{
    private AsyncEventHandler _asyncEventHandler;

    public void AddEventListener(EventListener listener) { _asyncEventHandler.AddEventListener(listener); }

    private void FireSomeEvent()
    {
        var eventArgs = new EventArgs();
        ...
        _asyncEventhandler.NotifyListeners(eventArgs);
    }
}
```

Now your original class isn't responsible for anything it wasn't responsible for before. It knows how to add listeners to itself and it knows how to tell its listeners that an event has occurred. The new class knows the implementation details of "tell its listeners that an event has occurred". Listener order is also preserved if it's important. It probably shouldn't be, though. If listenerB can't handle an event until listenerA has already handled it then listenerB is probably more interested in an event generated by listenerA than by the object it was listening to. Either that or you should have another class whose responsibility is to know the order that an event needs to be processed in.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I'm sorry if I was not clear enough but this is exactly what I tried to describe in the first option anyway. The reason I mentioned SoC is that the code has to have a reason to fire the event asynchronously in the first place. Why fire an event asynchronously? Because handlers may block. Does the firing method really have to consider this, though? This is  why I mentioned SoC. By the way, with "processing order of events" I meant the firing order of different events wrt to each other, rather than the processing order of a single event by different handlers.